# I am unable to use cropper image library because while adding cropper activity it is showing error. my menifest.xml is here

Tags: java, android, libraries, crop, image-cropper

**i am adding these activity in menifestfile but showing red line and error unresolve**

```
    <activity
                android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"     
                android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```

**this is manifest.xml file I add an activity for image cropper but showing error**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            package="com.example.imagetest">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
                android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Imagetest"
                tools:targetApi="31">
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"     
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        </application>    
        </manifest>
```

**this is gradelfile in which crop library include**

```
 

plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    }
    android {
        compileSdk 32    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.imagetest"
            minSdk 21
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    }
```

**here is setting.gradlefile**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "imagetest"
include ':app'
```

more details of the question is ..................................................

`i am getting get lines in menifestfile under activity for crop image. please someone help me`